# Add user in group

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution, groups, user

I'm trying to add a user in a group during my event `itemupdated`.

Like this he has the necessary permission to move a file and after I remove him from group.

I've tried this to add but nothing appears in the group and the code runs correctly in debug:

```
//manage permission to delete 
SPUser user = Web.CurrentUser;
SPGroup groupAdmin = Web.Groups["Admin test"];
bool permToRemove = false;
if (user != null && groupAdmin != null)
{
    if (!Web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupAdmin.ID))
    {
        groupAdmin.AddUser(user);
        permToRemove = true;
        user.Update();
    }
}
```

I'm in a sandbox solution.

Comment: Is this an event receiver? Is web the root web of the site collection? Also any reason why user.Update() us being used when you are not updating its properties?

Comment: Can you confirm that Web.CurrentUser is not a system account or null? Since your code is executed inside of `ItemUpdated` not `ItemUpdating`, HttpContext is currently null and user may be unknown at this point.

Comment: i'm at the root of the site inside event receiver itemupdated. It's not a system account and nothing is null because it goes in my if condition. Are there an other way to update user? i tryied too update group without success